# How do I display the correct day of the week for each of the 5 days in a weather forecast app using JS?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

So I'm having a bit of trouble. I've managed to pull only the day of the week from the date data retrieved from the openweathermap API, but I'm having trouble getting it to correctly display the day of the week for each of the 5 days I'm trying to include in the forecast. It's just assigning the same weekday name to each day of the forecast. Anyone able to help?

```
fetch(forecast)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        
        data.list.forEach(list => {
            
            const iconId = list.weather[0].id;

            
            const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
            const d = new Date(data.list[0].dt * 1000);
            const dayName = days[d.getDay()];
            console.log(dayName)

            // Generate and append html elements on the page
            const container = document.querySelector('.container');
            
            const forecastCard = document.createElement('div');
            container.appendChild(forecastCard)
            forecastCard.classList.add('forecast-card')

            const date = document.createElement('h2');
            date.textContent = dayName;
            forecastCard.appendChild(date);
            date.classList.add('date');

            const currentTemp = document.createElement('p');
            currentTemp.textContent = list.main.temp;
            forecastCard.appendChild(currentTemp);
            currentTemp.classList.add('current-temp');
            
            const icon = document.createElement('img');
            icon.src = `./icons/${list.weather[0].icon}.png`;
            forecastCard.appendChild(icon);
            icon.classList.add('icon');
            
            const conditions = document.createElement('p');
            conditions.textContent = list.weather[0].description;
            forecastCard.appendChild(conditions);
            conditions.classList.add('conditions');
            
            const humidity = document.createElement('p');
            humidity.textContent = `Humidity: ${list.main.humidity}%`;
            forecastCard.appendChild(humidity);
            humidity.classList.add('humidity');
            
    })
                    
    });
```

Comment: What is inside `data.list`? it may be a problem with the data and not your dayName

Comment: @PietroNadalini `data.list` is an array that contains the objects for each of the 5 days in the weather forecast. Within those objects is the dt property that the full date is pulled from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to define a datalist inside date:

```
let d = new Date();
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
let weekDay = days[d.getDay()];
console.log(weekDay);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either, it still assigns the same weekday name to each day in the forecast